# Square Value at Index without using a temp array

Tags: java, arrays

At 0th index value is 4, so I have to check the value at index 4 and square it and place the value at 0th index without using a temp array:

```
Index  0 1 2 3 4
Values 4 3 1 2 0
================
Result 0 4 9 1 16
```

Now I am getting the first two values right, but the last three are not right. My code is as below:

```
static void Index(int arr[], int n) {
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        int index = arr[i];
        int value = arr[index];
        arr[i]=value*value;
        
    }
}
```

Below is the output that I am getting:

```
Original Array
4 3 1 2 0 
Array after Squaring 
0 4 16 256 0
```

Can anyone help me out here as to what am I doing wrong?

Comment: don't use the title section for your description, that's what the description section is for.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Ok I will edit It now

Comment: In your method, what is the actual true purpose of the ***n*** parameter?

Comment: @JoeC When i=0, value=0, index=4

Comment: @DevilsHnd it is the length of the array

Comment: Currently, you are calculating next values based on other results, not on original values at indexes. If "without using temp array" is mandatory requirement then you can try using recursion. Just remember to call method recursively before placing calculated data to array, and after gathering all information needed to calculate it.

Comment: The length of your array is: `arr.length`, not ***n***. What your saying then is that you really don't need ***n***.

Comment: You are changing the values in the original array too soon, instead of making placing your computed values into a new array. More complete answer coming soon.

Comment: @DevilsHnd I have assigned int n = arr.length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the numbers are within range `[0, 46341)`, we can store both the old and the new values in the array during the process (as 32 bits are enough). Then after the first loop we do another one to discard the old values and square the new ones.

```
// assume array[i] is within range [0, 46341) for any i
static void f(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int j = array[i] & 0xffff; // get old value
        array[i] = array[j] << 16 | j; // put new and old values
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int j = array[i] >>> 16; // get new value
        array[i] = j * j; // put new value squared
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: This approach is valid only if length of array is less than 10.
I have completed this code using only one loop without using any extra space.
Although, I have set a flag to run the complete loop twice.
If you do not have any constraint of using one loop, you can avoid using the flag and simply use two loops.

Approach:

```
Index           0  1  2  3  4
Values          4  3  1  2  0 
Updated value  04 23 31 12 40
```

You must have got the idea what I did here.
I put the values at tens place whose square is to be displayed.
Now you have to just have to iterate once more and put the square of tens place at that index
Here's the code:

```
void sq(int arr[], int n){
    bool flag = false;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(!flag){
            if(arr[arr[i]] < 10){
                arr[i] += (arr[arr[i]] * 10);
            }
            else{
                arr[i] += ((arr[arr[i]]%10) * 10);
            }
        }
        if(i==n-1 && !flag){
            i=0;
            flag = true;
        }
        if(flag)
            arr[i] = (arr[i]/10) * (arr[i]/10);
    }
}
```

It is in C++.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are changing the values in your original array. In you current implementation this is how your array changes on each iteration:

```
{4, 3, 1, 2, 0} 
{0, 3, 1, 2, 0} 
{0, 4, 1, 2, 0} 
{0, 4, 16, 2, 0} 
{0, 4, 16, 256, 0}
```

The problem is you still need the values stored in the original array for each iteration. So the solution is to leave the original array untouched and put your values into a new array.

```
    public static void index(int arr[]) {
    int[] arr2 = new int[arr.length];
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        int index = arr[i];
        int value = arr[index];
        arr2[i]=value*value;
    }
}
```

Values of arr2 in revised process:

```
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0} 
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0} 
{0, 4, 0, 0, 0} 
{0, 4, 9, 0, 0} 
{0, 4, 9, 1, 0} 
{0, 4, 9, 1, 16}
```

Comment: I can not use another array that is the condition This code will not be valid for my situation

Comment: @Ajinkya - Then the title to your post is somewhat conflicting since it says: **"... using temp array"**. Which is it?